# Why my div disappear when I hover it when it over his parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to construct a structure with 3 scrollbars, one on the top of the table one on the bottom and one tiny scrollbar that appear only if you hover the table(because it's a big table). And this tiny scrollbar should follow you until you get out of the table. So I construct the structure in 3 part.

the firsts two parts are litterally the tiny scrollbar and the top scrollbar. But the third part is more complex. Firstly we have the main div that contain all the div. Then I put the div to start the structure of the scrollbar. Then I put a div AND the table in the new div. The div next to the table aims to floating over the table to create a zone of interaction between the mouse of the user and the tiny scrollbar. I need this div because I don't want the whole table to have this type of interaction, indeed, the very top of the table and the very bottom of the table would normally don't have any interaction.

Once the tinybar appear because I hover the floating div I try to scroll it but it doesn't work because it disappear when I try to scroll it in the "main" div. I try to fix this by changing the position but it doesn't work. But I put top:10% on the tinybar and I added a paragraphe tag with a bottom padding of 100px to see what happen if th tiny bar is outof the main div: and it's works ! The Tiny scrollbar can work ony out of the main div.

So my question is how to fix that ? I want to scroll the tinybar even if my mouse is over the main div.

HTML:

```html
<p id="zola" style="padding-bottom: 100px">  <p>
<div class="wrapper_mobile" id="w_mob" onscroll="move_scrollbar_mobile()">
    <div class="child_mobile" id="w_mob_child">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper_top" id="w_top" onscroll="move_scrollbar_top()">
    <div class="child_top" id="w_top_child">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="main" style="position: relative" onmouseout="hide_scroll_mob()">

    <div class="wrapper_table" id="w_tab" onscroll="move_scrollbar_table()">
        <div class="wrapper_float" id="w_flo" onmouseover="disp_scroll_mob()">

        </div>
        <table class="search_table" id="w_tab_child">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Col1</th>
                    <th>Col2</th>
                    <th>Col3</th>
                    <th>Col4</th>
                    <th>Col5</th>
                    <th>Col6</th>
                    <th>Col7</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper_top, .wrapper_table{
    width: 300px;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     overflow-y:hidden;
}
 .wrapper_mobile{
    position: fixed;
     width: 100px;
     height: 50px;
   top: 10%;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     display: none;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: red;
   z-index: 2;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}

 .wrapper_float {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    top: 10%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #88FF88;
   z-index: 1;
}

 .wrapper_top{
    height: 20px;
}
 .wrapper_table{
    height: 200px;
}
 .child_top {
    width:1000px;
     height: 20px;
}

 .child_mobile {
     width:300px;
     height: 20px;
}
 .search_table{
     table-layout: fixed;
}
 th{
     font-size:15px;
     background:#66C2E0;
}
 th {
     min-width: 200px;
}
#main {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JS:

```js
let w_mob_len = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_mob_child'), null).width.replace("px", "") - getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_mob'), null).width.replace("px", "");
let w_top_len = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_top_child'), null).width.replace("px", "") - getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_top'), null).width.replace("px", "");
let w_tab_len = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_tab_child'), null).width.replace("px", "") - getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('w_tab'), null).width.replace("px", "");

function move_scrollbar_mobile(){
    let wrap_mob = document.getElementById("w_mob");
    let wrap_top = document.getElementById("w_top");
    let wrap_tab = document.getElementById("w_tab");
    wrap_top.scrollLeft = wrap_mob.scrollLeft * w_top_len/w_mob_len;
    wrap_tab.scrollLeft = wrap_mob.scrollLeft * w_tab_len/w_mob_len;
}

function move_scrollbar_top(){
    let wrap_mob = document.getElementById("w_mob");
    let wrap_top = document.getElementById("w_top");
    let wrap_tab = document.getElementById("w_tab");
    wrap_mob.scrollLeft = wrap_top.scrollLeft * w_mob_len/w_top_len;
    wrap_tab.scrollLeft = wrap_top.scrollLeft * w_tab_len/w_top_len;
}

function move_scrollbar_table(){
    let wrap_mob = document.getElementById("w_mob");
    let wrap_top = document.getElementById("w_top");
    let wrap_tab = document.getElementById("w_tab");
    wrap_mob.scrollLeft = wrap_tab.scrollLeft * w_mob_len/w_tab_len;
    wrap_top.scrollLeft = wrap_tab.scrollLeft * w_top_len/w_tab_len;
}

function disp_scroll_mob(){
    document.getElementById("w_mob").style.display = "inline-block";
}

function hide_scroll_mob(){
    document.getElementById("w_mob").style.display = "none";
}

function over_w3(){
    document.getElementById("w_mob").style.position = "absolute";
}
```

Comment: What happens when you remove `.wrapper_mobile:hover {
  position: absolute;
}`?

Comment: Yeah I tried something, I was thinking that it could correct the issue but it doesn't so you can ignore it i will delete it on the next edit

Comment: why are you adding position absolute on hover? is there any specific need to do so?

Comment: I agree with StackSlave, I don't see any issue with the code, unless you have any reason to have `hover` for that small scroll, check here https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/60r7pz3m/62/

Comment: @Manjuboyz what ?? it doesn't work on codepen, it's very strange... and I don't know why :(... I will try on my own website

Comment: No, the culprit is the property `hover` for sure, so removing that should work everywhere.

Comment: Ok ! I made a mistakes on the main div you should put onmouseout="hide_scroll_mob()" to trigger the problem ! I will add it on the original code I completly forgot it !

Comment: @Manjuboyz why your answer disappear ?

Comment: I deleted it since it wasn't helping you, it will not help you or anyone in SO.